# After upgrading to new Jenkins version, builds are failing

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, hudson

I just upgraded the jenkins from 2.63 to 2.117 (Which I'm regretting now)

Here is the error message I'm getting at the end of all the jobs.

Please help me to understand and resolve this.

```
    FATAL: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Refusing to marshal java.io.PrintStream for security reasons; see https://jenkins.io/redirect/class-filter/
    at hudson.util.XStream2$BlacklistedTypesConverter.marshal(XStream2.java:543)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize org.jenkinsci.plugins.EnvironmentVarSetter#log for class org.jenkinsci.plugins.EnvironmentVarSetter
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:256)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:224)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:88)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:74)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller$1.convertAnother(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:84)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshallField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:265)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:252)
Caused: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to serialize hudson.model.Actionable#actions for class hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.writeField(RobustReflectionConverter.java:256)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter$2.visit(RobustReflectionConverter.java:224)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:138)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.doMarshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:209)
    at hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter.marshal(RobustReflectionConverter.java:150)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractReferenceMarshaller.convert(AbstractReferenceMarshaller.java:69)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:58)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:43)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:82)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:37)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1026)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:1015)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:988)
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:193)
Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:200)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:1923)
    at hudson.model.Run.setDisplayName(Run.java:803)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.BuildNameSetter.setDisplayName(BuildNameSetter.java:76)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.BuildNameSetter.access$000(BuildNameSetter.java:31)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.buildnamesetter.BuildNameSetter$1.tearDown(BuildNameSetter.java:64)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:174)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:504)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1727)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:97)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:429)
```

Note: Others who are using older version of jenkins, there is a big chance that all your jobs will be messed up. So, Please do not update jenkins as of now. [(https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/03/15/jep-200-lts/)](https://jenkins.io/blog/2018/03/15/jep-200-lts/)

Comment: It sounds like you have lost your "write" right on Jenkins' file. Could you check the file Jenkins is trying to write on, and make sure that they have the right for it?

Comment: you meant to say the jenkins war file?

Comment: Caused: java.io.IOException
    at hudson.XmlFile.write(XmlFile.java:200)
    at hudson.model.Run.save(Run.java:1923) I mean this file, that is causing the exception

Comment: do you have Build-name-setter plugin? if not it may be other not updated plugin

Comment: @luc I think i can set the permission for that. But yes, let me check.

Comment: I will update the name setter plugin and check if it works

Answer (score 0):

You can try the solution given in the official site of Jenkins
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49144

Add the three following entries to whitelisted-classes.txt:

```
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock
java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync
java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject
```

Comment: Okay. But, i'm bit new for this stuff. Where can i find the whitelisted-classes.txt?

Answer (score 0):

It is to do with the two things.

1. Permission to be updated to the .war file.
2. Build Pipeline plugin needs to be updated.

This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known security fix in Jenkins https://github.com/jenkinsci/jep/tree/master/jep/200.

You can check list of affected plugins https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Plugins+affected+by+fix+for+JEP-200 and upgrade your affected ones to overcome the error.